# I want an cool urban/track bike with 3speeds. Could you recommend me one?

Tags: commuter, urban-riding

Good afternoon,

I would like to buy a cool urban bike based on track design: sort like a tuned fuji feather and so forth. I would like it to be light and instead of a single speed, have 3 speeds. I want a simple cool urban bike I can fix myself, but not a fixie or a single speed which is not enough because I like the road too.

I have been looking all over the place and can't find any bike that suits me.

Can you recommend me one?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Given that the defining characteristic of a track bike *is* its fixed-gear nature, exactly what traits are you looking for?

Comment: This really isn't the best forum for shopping - you'll get more response if you ask questions that produce information usable to others down the road. Maybe could you reword your question to talk about the virtues/pitfalls of 3-speeds vs. single-speed vs. fixed on a city bike? What to look for in a user-serviceable urban track-style bike? Maybe provide more info on climate (because cold and icy requires different gear than hot and humid.)

Comment: @StephenTouset Apparently what flaab is looking for is: a) "cool" b) light-weight c) 3-speed d) user-serviceable. "Based on track design" might mean that it looks fast and simple/minimal.

Comment: Also, it'd be nice to know the whats and hows of your desired bike. The difference being between a skinny-tire, neon-frame-pad-type ride or a fatter tire, moustache-bar, leather saddle-type ride (and every other fashion/mode/style/fad/ethic of ride!) (i.e. most track frames don't allow for 32mm tires and fenders.)

Comment: Hi :-) Thanks for answering. I like the "featherish and sport" style but applied for an urban bike. But I want three speeds and brakes. A nice one: http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5301/5562726692_eb6f64c734.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what you mean. I had the same desires and I ended up buying an SE Draft on ebay and fitting a wheel with a 3 speed hub. If you can find a bike shop that are keen on building and customising they might be able to sell you a single speed bike and then fit a 3 speed hub.

An Australian online store, [Jelly Bean bikes](http://www.jellybeanbikes.com.au/) give the option of buying the bike with a 3 speed hub, but they don't ship overseas. You might be able to find a similar store near you.

Comment: Do you know what 3 speed hub they use?

Comment: I think I've read that they use a shimano 3 speed hub. I went with a Sturmey Archer S-RF3

Comment: Cheers Mac. Do these both fit a 120mm OLD frame?

Comment: @PaulTDavies I'm not sure... I took my bike in and asked for a hub to fit it because I've been bitten by this issue before.